# function is not hitting public site

Tags: azure-functions

I created a function app and storage account in the private network.
The function app is integrated with Vnet, and private endpoint and disables access restriction.
In the storage account enable selected Vnets only.

I created a queue trigger to connect to a public site and do some jobs, and save the output data in a storage account, but the function is not hitting that public site.

Note: I tried with another function app and storage account with a public network. it's working fine.

please help to hit the public site. what I need to do.
I need all resources with a private network only.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Azure Private Site access to connect your Azure Function to from VNET and outside of it.

In order to enable Azure Private site access, Deploy one VM with Vnet like below:-

[image]

Then I created one Bastion resource to connect to my Function app from Browser with VM connected to Bastion in the same Vnet as my Function app. Just the AzureBastionSubnet is a dedicated subnet created for Bastion host to work.

[image]

My Vnet:-

[image]

I enabled Access restriction and selected the previously created Subnet, When I tried accessing Function URL via my computer's browser I received 403 Error Forbidden like below:-

[image]

[image]

Now, Lets access the Function URL via VM's Bastion host in browser:-

[image]

Now, I created one HTTP Trigger Function and Tried accessing it via my computer's Browser which gave me an 403 error, When I tried accessing the Function Http Trigger URL via Bastion, I was able to access the trigger.

[image]

**Via Bastion Host:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/functions-create-private-site-access.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-create-private-site-access.md)